# Is there a standard way to preserve const correctness of underlying objects in smart pointers members?

Tags: c++

Say you have the following classes:

```
class Bar {
public:
    int nonConstFunc();
};

class Foo {
public:
    int someConstFunction() const
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> m_bar;
};
```

Is there any way to enforce that we cannot call non-const functions of Bar inside the Foo's const functions? If we did not use a smart pointer here, this would not be a problem.
This is mostly theoretical, but can be the source of mistakes that go unnoticed.

I came up with this solution:

```
template<class T>
class smart_ptr
{
public:
    smart_ptr() = default;
    smart_ptr(typename T::element_type *u)
        : m_ptr(u)
    {
    }

    typename T::element_type *operator->() { return m_ptr.get(); }
    const typename T::element_type *operator->() const { return static_cast<const typename T::element_type *>(m_ptr.get()); }

private:
    T m_ptr;
};
```

And then use smart_ptr<std::shared_ptr< Bar >> m_bar; instead, but I'm wondering if there's a standard solution to this problem.

Comment: tl;dr: [std::experimental::propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)

Comment: [propogate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) was considered for standarization. You can find reference implementations online.

Comment: propagate_const  seems to be exactly what I was looking for, too bad it's not standard yet.